# Sqlite to Postgresql Migration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

Current application we are using sqlite database and now we have to migrate from sqlite to Postgresql.I have migrated using sequel as below

sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname

After migration i am facing syntax error as below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "devices" WHERE  (User_id IS 6 AND mac_address IS "88:83:123:31:68")
```

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6"
LINE 1: ...ECT COUNT(*) FROM "devices" WHERE (User_id IS 6 AND mac..)

My Controller i have used below query for above syntax

```
 @device_by_user = Device.where("User_id IS #{id} AND mac_address IS \"#{mac}\"")
```

It is requiring below query syntax for PostgreSQL where field names starting with Upper case are enclosed with quotes and text value should be enclosed in single quote.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "devices" WHERE "User_id"=6 AND mac_address= '88:83:123:31:68';
```

Do i need to change syntax wherever it is applicable? or Is there any other approach available in rails?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I would consider going through the schema and creating migrations to rename the columns to `snake_case` as these kind of inconsistencies will just lead to unessicary bugs in the future.

Comment: In SQL, double quotes indicate a quoted identifier like a table or column name, and single quotes a string. Sqlite just has the unusual behavior of treating a double quoted value that's not a known identifier as a string. I think it's for some attempt at MySQL compatibility. If you use parameters and bind values to them like you should be, it becomes a moot point for strings though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
Device.where({ :user_id => 6, :mac_address => '88:83:123:31:68'}).count
```

It should work if your model is correct.
Hope that helps